# Visualizing daily and weekly recording times in Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I'm building an app for recording work hours in Django, and I'd like to be able to visualize the data by graphing the daily and weekly records together, but how do I create data to display in a line graph like the one below?

- Backend：Django
- Frontend：React
- Chart：[ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/)

[image]

Django / model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,
                                related_name='entries',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='entries',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.project.name, self.created_at)
```

I was able to get the daily data by using the following method, but how can I display the data for days with no records (days with zero records)?

```
def get_report(self, obj):
    data = Entry.objects.all().values(
        'created_at__year', 'created_at__month', 'created_at__day').annotate(
            Sum('time')).order_by('created_at__year', 'created_at__month',
                                  'created_at__day')
    return data
```

**currently**

```
"report": [
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 18,
        "time__sum": 1221
    },
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 22,
        "time__sum": 1201
    },
],
```

**Ideal shape(Display 0 even when there is no record.)**

```
"report": [
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 18,
        "time__sum": 1221
    },
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 19,
        "time__sum": 0
    },
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 20,
        "time__sum": 0
    },
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 21,
        "time__sum": 0
    },
    {
        "created_at__year": 2021,
        "created_at__month": 2,
        "created_at__day": 22,
        "time__sum": 1201
    },
],
```

Comment: The database can't produce what it doesn't have. This simply means you will have to fill the missing dates yourself. (Some looping yourself or you can try using pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates with no records are not in the database and so, the database would not send any report on them.

you can use the datetime module though.
i will give you a pseudo-code to try.

```
for date in the created_date__month
    if date not in report:
        report.append({... time__sum: 0})
```

i hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried the above code and got an error like `name 'created_data__month' is not defined.` I've had similar errors before when I tried to extract things from data.

Comment: What I gave you is a pseudo code. Like an algorithm. I will get back to you with correct code when I can.